# Can you put git revision information in a multifile document?

Tags: header-footer, include, revision-control, git

I have my PhD thesis under revision control (git), with a master file `(~/Thesis/thesis.tex)` using the `\include` command to include the chapters (`~/Thesis/tex/chapter1.tex`, etc).

Is there a way to include the revision information of each separate chapter in the header of each page for each respective chapter?

I thought I was getting somewhere with a combination of the [`gitinfo`](http://ctan.org/pkg/gitinfo) and `fancyhdr` packages, but I'm not sure if you can have different revision headers under gitinfo.

Comment: You're correct; `gitinfo` only provides information for the current HEAD. I considered the approach you're suggesting, but it may be unsafe if, for example, you have a private style file in your project that affects the output, but doesn't actually "appear on a page". Knowing the revision id for the whole project *does* allow you to know exactly which versions of files were used, but obviously in a less-convenient manner.

Comment: I have a similar problem - would be great to pull revision information of each include and display as a footer.

Answer (score 7):

Not directly, no; git doesn't distinguish between files (or something like that) and it doesn't store metadata on the last revision that affected each file.

I think the best option would be to write a post-commit hook that looked at the changed files and wrote a timestamp corresponding to each. E.g., iterate through the output of

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only master
```

and write a `<filename>.datestamp` file when each file is seen. 
This file could then be read directly into a header/footer to show when the chapter was lasted edited.